# How to generate QR code which can be used to save contact in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, qr-code

I'm trying to generate a QR code which contains contact information about people and they can share the QR code.
The person when scans the QR code it should ask the person to save the contact.

Currently I'm using library qr_flutter
But it only shows text and it's not able to create a contact qr code

Comment: You can create a model class which contains toJson() and fromJson(), and add the data into it like this example: Contact(name: "john doe", phone: "9393938383"). Then convert this model class into toJson() this will give you a string, then create your qr code using this string. When you scan this qr code you'll get a json string then decode this back into your model class using fromJson(). Then you can have details of qr and save the contact.

Comment: You do not want to save this to JSON. You want to save this as VCF/VCARD. Then, when a user scans it, the device will automatically automatically offer to save the contact for you. Last time I did this, it worked seamlessly in iOS (i.e., scan, see a contact card with save button) and a little less elegantly in Android (i.e., scan, offer to save file, open that, then see the contact that can be saved), but it works fine.

Comment: In iOS, we use the Contacts framework’s `CNContactVCardSerialization` to convert contact to VCARD. I can’t speak to Android or Flutter…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a small example how you can show a contact card with the qr_flutter package.

```dart
final vcardData = 'BEGIN:VCARD\n'
  'VERSION:3.0\n'
  'N:Doe;John;;Mr.;\n'
  'TEL;TYPE=CELL:+33 0600000000\n'
  'EMAIL:john.doe@example.com\n'
  'END:VCARD';
```

```dart
QrImage(
  data: vcardData,
  version: QrVersions.auto,
  size: 300.0,
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  foregroundColor: Colors.black,
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
)
```

for this example I use `qr_flutter:4.0.0`

Comment: import 'package:qr_flutter/qr_flutter.dart'; on your component and   qr_flutter: 4.0.0 in the pubspec yaml